# Pentadactyl Firefox shortcuts

Tags: firefox, pentadactyl

The commands ZZ,:xa,:xall and :wq are supposed to save the current firefox session and quit,but regardless of which one I try I end up on my homepage the next time firefox is started.Are the commands supposed to work out of the box or should I add a specific entry to the pentarc, or edit the firefox option.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Firefox is set to remember your history when the session closes:

- Go to `about:preferences#privacy`
- Check that either `Firefox will:` is set to `Remember History`.
- Alternatively, if it's set to `Use Custom Settings for History`, make sure you've selected the settings to remember browser history and *not* to clear history when the session ends.